# Convert all CR to CRLF in text file using CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, newline

Is there a way to convert all CRs to CRLFs in a text file?

When I open a text file from Linux server on Windows, all text is displayed in one line, but actually it's a multi line one.

I'd like to perform the conversion in a batch file.

Can anyone advice, please?

Comment: FYI, Linux (and all other Unix variants and descendants too) uses LF as its line terminator (and calls it "newline") not CR. Old Mac operating systems did use CR however. Windows (and DOS before it, and CP/M-80 before that, and many other operating systems as well) use CR and LF together as the line terminator.

Comment: thanks for info, how can i do convertion in the batch file, any help on that

Comment: if the file comes from Linux then it should end with LF. Only old Mac uses CR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch file + convert LF to CR+LF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110031/batch-file-convert-lf-to-crlf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Line separators and line terminators have been a source of compatibility friction between systems as long as there has been more than one kind of system and an urge to exchange data. The [Wikipedia article on the Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) has a decent overview of the historical context. And, it suggests a variety of solutions to this problem specifically for use on the Unix side or the Windows side.

On the Unix (Linux) side, look for a utility named `unix2dos` and its close relative `dos2unix`. These are commonly available, either as a component of a commercial Unix or as open source tools. If available, they are the best answer because they (usually, see your verson's man pages for details) are careful about files that are accidentally written with both line endings. In that unfortunate case, a trip through both utilities will usually clean up the file to be internally consistent. In the absence of these convenient commands, many native utilities can be made to do the conversion. For instance, converting DOS CRLF line endings to Unix newlines can be done with the `tr` command:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < inputfile > outputfile
```

But do note the caveat that this command assumed that all lines were terminated by CRLF (or LFCR) and works by simply deleting every CR character from the input. Any naked CR characters will be lost.

On the DOS and Windows side, it used to be a lot bleaker. Ports of `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` certainly exist, for instance they are included in the *much* larger Cygwin tools that provide a complete unix emulation on a Windows machine. But a solution using only built-in features was hard to find.

Modern Windows (probably since Windows XP), however, is better. There, the built-in FIND command is much less touchy about choice of line terminator than it used to be, and can be used to do the required conversion from Unix line endings to DOS endings. The Wiki page cited above gives this recipe:

```
C:\...> TYPE filename.u | FIND "" /V >filename.txt
```

Experimentation shows that this works as well, but it may not give identical results for unknown reasons:

```
C:\...> FIND "" /V <filename.u >filename.txt
```

In both cases, you create a copy of the file with the changed line endings. It would probably not be recommended to change the files in place.

I'll mention one other approach that always seems tempting on paper. When you use Samba to provide the file system share on the Linux server for mounting by Windows, there is a configuration option you can set for the share that mounts it in "text mode". Shares mounted in "text mode" automatically have line endings converted. If it works for you, that is probably the cleanest possible solution. Both systems use their preferred text file format, and neither has to fuss about it. But test carefully, this solution is full of edge cases and pitfalls. Most importantly, don't expect binary files on a text mode file system mount point to read correctly. They often will, but not necessarily always.

Comment: `TYPE ./public-key.pem | FIND "" /V > p.pem` returns `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: To fix "The syntax of the command is incorrect." make sure that you don't use paths, just file names. For example, this *won't* work: `TYPE folder/file.txt ...`, use `cd folder && TYPE file.txt ...` instead

Answer (score 7):

```
type inputfile | find /v "" > outputfile
```

That should do it. `type` reads input file and pipes output to `find` with parameters to match all lines and output them to output file. In the process, LF is converted to CRLF

Answer (score 3):

A possible though quite cumbersome way is to use [`CertUtil.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html), an executable that is natively included since past Windows XP, if I remember correctly. Here is a possible script (let us call it `conv-eol.bat`; see all the explanatory `rem` remarks in the code):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_IFILE=%~1"  & rem // (input file; first command line argument)
set "_OFILE=%~2"  & rem // (output file; second command line argument)
set "_IEOL=0d"    & rem // (incoming line-breaks; `0d` or `0a`)
set "_OEOL=0d 0a" & rem // (outgoing line-breaks; `0d`, `0a`, `0d 0a`, ``)
set "_TFILE1=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.hex" & rem // (first temporary file)
set "_TFILE2=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (second temporary file)

rem // Verify input file:
< "%_IFILE%" rem/ || exit /B
rem // Convert input file to hexadecimal values (first temporary file):
CertUtil -f -encodehex "%_IFILE%" "%_TFILE1%" 4 > nul
rem // Write to second temporary file:
> "%_TFILE2%" (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Read first temporary file line by line:
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("!_TFILE1!") do (
        rem /* Store current line (hex. values), then replace line-breaks
        rem    using the given line-break codes and return result: */
        set "LINE=%%L" & echo(!LINE:%_IEOL%=%_OEOL%!
    )
    endlocal
)
rem // Verify output file:
> "%_OFILE%" rem/ || exit /B
rem // Convert second temporary file back to text into output file:
CertUtil -f -decodehex "%_TFILE2%" "%_OFILE%" 4 > nul
rem // Clean up temporary files:
del "%_TFILE1%" "%_TFILE2%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Provide the input file as the first command line argument and the output file as the second one to the script (they may even equal):

> ```cmd
> conv-eol.bat "input-file.txt" "output-file.txt"
> ```

The input and output line-breaks must be specified as hexadecimal character codes, while `0d` represents the carriage-return (CR) and `0a` the line-feed (LF) character.

The following table tells how to set the variables `_IEOL` and `_OEOL` at the top of the script for different line-break style conversion tasks:

> ```cmd
> from       \       to||Mac (CR)             ||Unix/Linux (LF)      ||DOS/Windows (CR+LF)  
> Mac (CR)             ||#####################||_IEOL=0d, _OEOL=0a   ||_IEOL=0d, _OEOL=0d 0a
> Unix/Linux (LF)      ||_IEOL=0a, _OEOL=0d   ||#####################||_IEOL=0a, _OEOL=0d 0a
> DOS/Windows (CR+LF)  ||_IEOL=0a, _OEOL=     ||_IEOL=0d, _OEOL=     ||#####################
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/\R/\n/g'
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: OP is asking for a Windows CMD solution and this unix solution requires two programs not typically found in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The following batch fragment does the trick:

```
del outputfile
for /f "delims=" %%x in (inputfile) do echo %%x>>outputfile
```

Its advantage is not relying on the `find` program, which is rather temperamental (hangs or doesn't work on some machines where I tested the other solutions).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP and earlier, you can convert a text file to CRLF simply by opening and saving it in Dos Edit (or Windows Edit).  Unfortunately, the Edit program was removed in Vista.

Answer (score 0):

One ridiculous way. Works with the following scenarios:

1. Text file with a CR at end of every line.
2. Text file with a repeating set of CR at end of line followed by an empty line with CRLF. Good luck!

Open the file in Notepad++ (free app) and set View -> All Characters.

IF all lines end in CR then:

1. Open in Microsoft Wordpad - NOT - Word and save the file in MSDOS-Format.
   ELSE IF lines end in CR followed by a blank line ending with CRLF then
2. remove the blank lines first with Notepad++. Go to Edit -> Line Operations -> Remove empty lines and save the file.
3. Open the file in Microsoft Wordpad and save in MSDOS-Format.

END IF