# Git Extensions change setting line endings and force commit file to git remote

Tags: git, line-endings, git-extensions

I have a problem with the line terminator CR LF.

before I had set line endings like No Set,
but this did not allow me to load the files correctly on the remote git with a commit and push.

Remotely the file was loaded correctly but there was only the presence of LF and CR was missing

Example
Upload
pippi pluto CR LF

Commit and push 
git remote 
pippo pluto LF

I changed the setting line endings with:Checkout is-as, commit as-is core.autocrlf is set to false

[image: Set config View]

Now the file is loaded correctly ( line endings CR LF)  on git remote through commit and push 
but only when the file is new

Old files remain with the problem of line termination ( only LF but missing CR ). 
Git does not allow me to reload the files with the correct terminators (CR LF) as git are identical but remotely is missing the terminator (only LF).

How can I force the re-upload of the incorrect files with correct file or of the whole directory containing these files (there are many files that have this problem) ?

thank you
Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

For Git Extensions; Tools>>Settings>>Git>>Config

[image: View Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

With the option you choose "Checkout is-as, commit as-is" (that I also recommend when using only one OS), git is no more touching/converting the files when commuting them.

So you have to do a massive correction of all files before committing them.

There are a lot of way to do it (not all perfect or convenient). Choose the one with tools you have:

- [Way to convert CR to CRLF in the text file for all the lines using CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912941/way-to-convert-cr-to-crlf-in-the-text-file-for-all-the-lines-using-cmd)
- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos
- [Windows command to convert Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings)
- [Change EOL on multiple files in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341660/change-eol-on-multiple-files-in-one-go)

Answer (score 0):

In **.gitattributes** file type `*.yourextension -text` to force all files with extension "yourextension", or type `* -text` instead of `* text=auto`

> the path is marked for automatic end-of-line conversion. If Git
>   decides that the content is text, its line endings are converted to LF
>   on checkin. **When the file has been committed with CRLF, no conversion
>   is done.**

[Set to string value "auto"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-Settostringvalueauto)

referring to your

> Old files remain with the problem...

So, you can also wrap into json and save the text `"MyContent1\r\nMyContent2\nMyContent3"`